# OSError: [Errno 22} Invalid argument: 'downloaded/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4'

Tags: python, web-scraping

> tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
>
> OSError: [Errno 22} Invalid argument: 'downloaded/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4'

Can anyone help me with this error? I figure it has something to do with `jquery.js?v=1.4.4` not being valid. I am new at python; I apologize if I am missing something obvious.

Here is the code:

```
import os
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

downloadDirectory = "downloaded"
baseUrl = "http://pythonscraping.com"

def getAbsoluteURL(baseUrl, source):
    if source.startswith("http://www."):
        url = "http://"+source[11:]
    elif source.startswith("http://"):
        url = source
    elif source.startswith("www."):
        url = source[4:]
        url = "http://"+source
    else:
        url = baseUrl+"/"+source
    if baseUrl not in url:
        return None
    return url

def getDownloadPath(baseUrl, absoluteUrl, downloadDirectory):
    path = absoluteUrl.replace("www.", "")
    path = path.replace(baseUrl, "")
    path = downloadDirectory+path
    directory = os.path.dirname(path)

    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

    return path

html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
downloadList = bsObj.findAll(src=True)

for download in downloadList:
    fileUrl = getAbsoluteURL(baseUrl, download["src"])
    if fileUrl is not None:
        print(fileUrl)
        urlretrieve(fileUrl, getDownloadPath(baseUrl, fileUrl, downloadDirectory))
```

Comment: It not a valid file for download , maybe it's not the right link for download file .

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the function `urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)`,
the argument you give for the `filename` parameter needs to be a valid file name on your operating system.

In this case, when you run

```
urlretrieve(fileUrl, getDownloadPath(baseUrl, fileUrl, downloadDirectory))
```

the argument you give for `url` is "http://pythonscraping.com/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4", and the argument you give for `filename` is "downloaded/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4".

"jquery.js?v=1.4.4" I believe is not a valid file name.

Solution: in the `getDownloadPath` function, change `return path` to

```
return path.partition('?')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

downloaded/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4 is not a valid file name.
I think a better solution like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

download_directory = "downloaded"
base_url = "http://www.pythonscraping.com/"
# Use Requests instead urllib
def get_files_url(base_url):
    # Return a list of tag elements that contain src attrs
    html = requests.get(base_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
    return soup.find_all(src=True)

def get_file_name(url):
    # Return the last part after the last "/" as file name
    # Eg: return a.png as file name if url=http://pythonscraping.com/a.png
    # Remove characters not valid in file name
    file_name = url.split("/")[-1]
    remove_list = "?><\/:\"*|"
    for ch in remove_list:
        if ch in file_name:
            file_name = file_name.replace(ch, "")
    return download_directory + "/" + file_name

def get_formatted_url(url):
    if not url.startswith("http://"):
        return base_url + url
    elif base_url not in url:
        return None
    else:
        return url

links = get_files_url(base_url)

for link in links:
    url = link["src"]
    url = get_formatted_url(url)
    if url is None:
        continue
    print(url)
    result = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    file_name = get_file_name(url)
    print(file_name)
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in result.iter_content(10):
            f.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the **getDownloadPath** function like this:

```
def getDownloadPath(baseUrl, absoluteUrl, downloadDirectory):
    remove_list = '?<>\/:\"*|'
    for ch in remove_list:
        if ch in absoluteUrl:
            absoluteUrl = absoluteUrl.replace(ch, '')

        path = absoluteUrl.replace('www.', '')
        path = path.replace(baseUrl, '')
        path = downloadDirectory + '/' + path
        directory = os.path.dirname(path)

        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)

        return path
```